# What is the difference between repository and dependency in Maven?

Tags: maven, dependencies

How are they different? Or are they the same?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Repository is a collection of artifacts (eg: jars). You can think of it as a mere storage / cache of various artifacts.

Dependency is a situation where your project dependent on another artifact to perform its task (eg: compile, run, unit test)

On a maven project you typically declare what artifacts you need on the `<dependency>` section of your pom, and you can also declare what repositories maven should lookup the dependency from at the `<repositories>` section.

By default maven will lookup the artifacts on the [central repository](http://search.maven.org). But it's common for an organization to have an internal repository containing in-house developed artifacts. Hence typically `<repositories>` section on the pom is configured with this.

http://maven.apache.org/guides/index.html

Comment: Thanks, great answer. So for some dependencies I require to provide both the repository and the dependency, but for the ones in mavens repository, the dependency is enough?

Comment: Correct. Only add a repository to your pom if you know your dependency is nowhere to be found on central repository. You should also read about repository lookup rule, proxying and mirroring. On the maven documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The repository is where your libraries (aka artifacts) are stored.
Dependencies are the names of the libaries that your corrent project depends on

Comment: But repsotiries are online as well? And it also downloads jar files right?

Comment: Right @KorayTugay