# Dependencies and Repositories?

Tags: maven, dependencies, repository

I am new to Maven and I previously saw another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057138/what-is-the-difference-between-repository-and-dependency-in-maven) regarding the similar thing but I am still confused.

What is the difference between dependencies and repository in relation to libraries? 
I am aware that dependencies contain libraries that the project can be referred to. But how would it relate to external dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

When you use maven there is a chain of repostitories.  Each repository containers a store of library code, uniquely identified by group/artifact/version (GAV).

1) At the top level is [maven central](https://search.maven.org/) on the internet.

2) At the next level their is usally a corporate repository, Nexus or JFrog or similar.

3) On your local machine their is a repository, usually under your home directory .m2/repo

When you include a dependency in a pom like :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and then do a maven build it will go up the tree looking first in your local repo, then in your corporate, then finally in maven-central.  Each time it runs it will download the dependency to your local repo so it is ready next time.

Comment: Step 2 will only being done if configured accordingly.

Comment: Then what are the difference between remote repository and external dependency? Tutorialspoint and maven's guide confused me alot.